# Convert JavaScript for loop to php

Tags: javascript, php, for-loop

I'm a php noob and can't seem to crack the following;
I have the following javascript for loop:

```
function cz(accuracy) {
 for (var n = 10, o = 2; 320 * n > accuracy; )
   n /= 2,
   o++;
   return Math.min(16, o)
 }
```

And want to covert this loop to php.
I got to this but its not working like it should:

```
function calcZoom($accuracy) {
  for ($n = 10, $o = 2; $n * 320 > $accuracy; ) {
    $n / 2;
    $o++;
  }
  return min(16, $o);
}
```

Comment: You need to say what you expect it to do, and what it's actually doing.

Comment: Having said that, I think you mean `$n /= 2`. Votes to close as a typo.

Comment: `$n / 2;` is not assigned to anything. Did you re-check this before posting? It's clearly different from the JS code

Comment: What do you mean _like it should_ what did you expect and what do you get as output?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php (first user contributed note)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have missed out the assignment operator in the PHP version of the script.

**Code snippet with the changes made**

```
function calcZoom($accuracy) {
  for ($n = 10, $o = 2; $n * 320 > $accuracy; ) {
    $n /= 2;
    $o++;
  }
  return min(16, $o);
}
```

**Code walkthrough:**

Since the statement was `$n / 2` the value of the variable did not change.

Changing it to an `$n /= 2` assigned the value to the variable and thus fixed your issue.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but really you should have just voted to close this. Assuming the OP wrote the JS code, they must understand compound assignments. This is likely just a typo, and even if it's not, this has be covered a thousand times before.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm new to SO and unaware of the vote to close option. Also I do not have privilege to downvote a question. As per community rules (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), I tried to answer a question in the answer section rather than discussing the same in the comment section. I'm unsure why someone would want to downvote this.

Comment: Likely because this answer is unnecessary because this question will likely be closed soon. And a comment wasn't necessary given other people had already pointed out that this is just a typo. I don't think your answer necessarily deserves a downvote, but try to make sure the questions you're answering are good questions.

Comment: So many people ask bad questions here. It's not worth your time answering all of them when the asker could / should have done proper research in the first place.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I understand, Yes you are right. Sure I'll make sure to answer good questions and Thank you.